# Pure Regular Expression replace n by n+1

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How do I replace every number n that matches a certain pattern with n+1 in VsCode?

E.g.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

---

Result.

```
2,3,4,5,6,7,
```

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nmsmith89.incrementor

Comment: There seems to be a hack for this, it requires several search-and-replace steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Regex doesn't look like the appropriate tool.

---

However, some regular expressions engine allow it, such as [vim's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195624/6320039):

```
s/<\zs\d\+\ze>/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g
```

And in sublime text there is a plugin for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940856/6320039

This said you could either use vim only for this task or help the community by creating a new plugin similar to the above example!